# Adding javascript to child theme

Tags: javascript, child-theme, headers

I want to apply some `javascript` to my `header` and want to know what the best way to implement it is.

here is the source that contains the javascript I'm including - https://codepen.io/kaemak/pen/mHyKa/

Should I create a new `javascript` file then add it to the `child theme`, if so then I'm unsure of what to call the file and will it apply to the head from this location?

Answer (score 28):

You should enqueue the script in child theme's functions.php.
for example if name of the js file is custom.js and if you place it under js folder in your child theme, then in functions.php you should add

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );
```

Here `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will return the directory of your child theme, then `array( 'jquery' )` would make your js load after jquery, if your script requires js then you should use this else you can remove or you can add the dependent script here, then the last parameter true, is to make your js load at the footer.

Comment: if he want to enqueue js from the child he have to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` or the newest function `get_theme_file_uri`.

Comment: `get_theme_file_uri` Searches in the stylesheet directory before the template directory so themes which inherit from a parent theme can just override one file, and he simply wants to add the new script from style-sheet directory, so `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` would be more suitable for this case.

Comment: `get_theme_file_uri` doesn't override anything if used in a child theme, you simply try to get the uri in child and if not exists in parent. In case of an asset the override is performed by the handle. Btw `get_template_directory_uri` only search in the parent theme. That's why I commented.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, create a new JavaScript file and just call it wherever you want, I would suggest to call it under footer that's the best way to call js files. 
You can add below code to your footer:

```
<script  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/filename.js"></script>
```

Comment: Adding JS directly is not best practice. It should be enqueued through `functions.php`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-274